# Why is there a skip option when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

When Installing Ubuntu (12.* or 13.04) on a machine, there's a final advertisement-like screen where it shows what software will be installed (With panels like "Have fun with your photos" with some details about Shotwell, etc)

At the bottom, there's a progressbar that can be expanded to show a log. There's also a "skip" button. It seems to be enabled even during some seemingly crucial steps.

I've installed Ubuntu many times now, however I've never clicked this button for fear of screwing up the installation<sup>1</sup>.

What is this button for? What does it skip?

<sup>1. I usually make dual boots, so there's a chance that playing with this may damage the bootloader and then I'll have to grub rescue, which I'd rather not do. Otherwise I'd experiment away.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This button skips attempts to download updates from Internet. If, during installation, Ubuntu detects any network, it attempts to get updates from it.

Comment: Oh, I see! This would actually be useful for me -- I'm usually installing Ubuntu behind a corporate proxy (so updates won't work until I've messed with `apt.conf`), so it's pointless to even have Ubuntu ask for updates. Thanks!

Comment: If so, just disable ethernet in NetworkManager during installation, that would speed things up a bit.

Comment: And, by the way, you should not mess with `apt.conf` because of proxy. Setting it in `System Settings - Network` is just enough.

Comment: It's an authenticated proxy, System Settings isn't enough. (And I meant university, not corporate :P). And yeah, usually ethernet is off.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino: "just disable ethernet in NetworkManager" -- YES! YES! YES!  This can speed things up immensely and will be my new go-to move for most installations -- it seems to work better than just pulling the plug, and it took effect immediately (it kick-started a running installation process).  Note however that in general you want to disable *all networking* (not Ethernet specifically).  I still don't know what the "skip" button does though.